CSS animated elements shifting in Firefox and Safari when changing viewport size, but works fine in Chrome
This is a minimal, reproducible example


body {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100vw;
}
.container {
    animation: moves 5s ease 0s normal forwards;
    /* transform: translate(-50vw, -50vh) translate(50%, 50%); */
}
@keyframes moves {
    0% {
    }
    100%{
        transform: translate(-50vw, -50vh) translate(50%, 50%);
    }
}     
<div class="container">
    hello
</div>



When running this in Chrome it will move the element from the middle of the screen to the top left side and stay there, changing the viewport size will not move it (which is what I want). But on Firefox and Safari changing the viewport size (by changing the window's size or just by opening Dev Tools) will cause the element to shift/slide away. And I have no idea how to "fix" it. If I don't use animation and instead only use translate directly (as shown in the comment), the problem won't occur.
I don't want to use left and top inside animation, because of this Laggy css animation

Let me clarify my question a bit, I mean that I want the element to stay still, not moving, after the animation end. It does stay still when using transform directly. but it does not (and shift away) when the transform is inside animation. By opening up Dev Tools at the end of the animation on Firefox or Safari it will cause the element to go out of view. But it stay still in Chrome. I want it to stay still in Firefox and Safari too. Sorry for posting here but I tried editing the post but the edit page won't show up.

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>Document</title>
        <style>
            body {
                display: flex;
                justify-content: center;
                align-items: center;
                height: 100vh;
                width: 100vw;
                margin: 0; /* Ensure there are no default margins */
                overflow: hidden; /* Prevent scrollbars from appearing */
            }
            .container {
                animation: moves 5s ease 0s normal forwards;
                white-space: nowrap; /* Prevent text from wrapping */
                /* transform: translate(-50vw, -50vh) translate(50%, 50%); */
            }
            @keyframes moves {
                0% {
                }
                100%{
                    transform: translate(-50vw, -50vh) translate(50%, 50%);
                }
            }            
        </style>
    </head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        hello
    </div>
</body>
</html>

Try this out :)
I have added meta data part to the head.
please let me know if it worked...
upvote if it was helpful.

Hey, thank for trying, unfortunately the problem is still not solved on Firefox. I haven't tested it on Safari yet.

have you refreshed it once u opened dev tools. It had worked for me when i refreshed the page once.

I mean the problem is that it moves when user resize the browser screen, dev tools is just part of it

i have added the meta data part to the header. please could u check it now.

Adding the metatag does not fix this issue, as it seems to be more of a calculation issue concering animations - animations dont tend to update their computed values in some browsers? Either way, this did not solve it.

yeah i agree ..
